# Counting number of partial flags

Tags: abstract-algebra

For a tuple ${m_{1},...,m_{s}}$, $\sum _{i}m_{i}=n$, 
call a collection of subspaces $V_{1}\subset ... \subset V_{s}=n$, 
such that the dimension of $V_{i}/V_{i-1}=m_{i}$ a partial flag of the type ${m_{1},...,m_{s}}$ 
Denote it by $V_{\bullet }$. The set of such flags is denoted by $Fl({m_{1},...,m_{s}})$. 
Find the number of elements in the set $Fl({m_{1},...,m_{s}})$.

We are discussing nilpotent elements and jordan normal form theorem

Comment: You need to provide more details. Is $V$ a complex vector space? or is it defined over a finite field? In the former case, the set is infinite.

Comment: Sorry forgot to add, V is defined over a finite filed of p element.

Comment: Hint: Start with an easier case, the set $Fl(m)$, in other words the set of $m$-dimensional subspaces of $V$. (This is also called the Grassmannian.) Do you know the number of elements in $Fl(m)$? Once you have worked that out, you can proceed by induction.

Comment: Sorry for asking for more clarification, I did calculate Fl(m), but I would like to know on what and how should I apply the induction

Comment: I am not sure if it is the sum or the product, or any other mathematical relation

Answer (score 0):

This can be calculated inductively as follows:

1. Count the number of $m_1$ dimensional subspaces of $V$.
2. Having chosen an $m_1$-dimensional subspace $V_1$, the number of partial flags in $V$ containing $V_1$ is the same as the number of flags in the $(n-m_1)$-dimensional vector space $V/V_1$ of type $m_2,\ldots,m_s$.

Putting (1) and (2) together, you deduce that the number of flags of type $m_1,\ldots,m_s$ is equal to the number of $m_1$-dimensional subspaces of $V$ multiplied by the number of flags of type $m_2,\ldots,m_s$:
$$Fl(m_1,\ldots,m_s)=Fl(m_1)Fl(m_2,\ldots,m_s).$$

So, the key is to obtain the count in (1). Can you finish?